# timer elapsed time after pausing timer

Tags: c#, timer

What happens for a system.timer when it's enabled property changes from true to false and then back to true? Does it reset the elapsed time to 0 or does it continue from the elapsed time before the enabled property was first set to false?

Comment: Have you tried testing what happens when you set the timer as you say and log the results and inspected them? This seems like a question you could easily answer yourself...

Comment: You are absolutely right. Apologies.

Comment: Good job :D Keep contributing to SO :D It can be really rewarding!

Answer (score 0):

Setting a timer's enabled property to false resets the elapsed (current) time to zero. Thus, when the enabled property changes from true to false and then back to true, the timer will start counting from zero.